# Add data interval for the x-axis stripplot in python

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am using stripplot in python where in axis I have time range from 3601 to 8600 in seconds. But from figure It's hard to see the time in  x-axis. How can I add specific interval (like the y-axis in my figure) to make it visible? Here is my code to generate the figure.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
# Visualising the plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
params_anno = dict(jitter=0.25,size=8, color='#91bfdb', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, dodge=False)
ax=sns.stripplot(x=dataset["Time"], y=dataset["Ob7"],**params_anno)
params_anno = dict(data=dataset_2, x='Time', y='Ob7',jitter=0.25)
ax=sns.stripplot(size=8,color='red', edgecolor='black',linewidth=1,**params_anno)
```

Here is my figure

[image]
I have seen [seaborn.stripplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) documentations but couldn't find any suitable example. Does anybody help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `stripplot` at all? This is usually meant for categorical data while here you seem to have continuous numeric data, for which a usual scatter plot is much better suited.

Comment: I think I got your point. Let me try with usual scatter plot.  But Isn't it possible to add an interval here for continuous numerical data?

Comment: Why should there be such option? The documentation clearly states "Draw a scatterplot where one variable is categorical." Since you apparently want none of the variables as categorical, this is simply not the function to use here.

Answer (score 0):

The question is alredy 5months old, but if someone need answer.

*You can try this:*

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig,axs = plt.subplots()
axs.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.05))
```